# Trying to create a timestamp "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm a" for a chat for android using java

Tags: java, android, timestamp, mobile-development

I am trying to create a timestamp in the format "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm a". My app was originally crashing but I tried a different method and it doesn't crash anymore but on the chat screen it shows "java.text.SimpleDateFormat@4f47c0fb" instead of the timestamp.

[Here is a screen shot of the chat screen timestamp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Mkjm.png)

This is from my AdapterChat.java file

```
    @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyHolder myHolder, int i) {
    //Get data
    String message = chatList.get(i).getMessage();
    String timeStamp = chatList.get(i).getTimestamp();

    //Convert time stamp to mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm am/pm
    //Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
    //cal.setTimeInMillis(Long.parseLong(timeStamp));
    String dateTime = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a", Locale.getDefault()).toString();


    //Set data
    myHolder.messageTv.setText(message);
    myHolder.timeTv.setText(dateTime);
    try {
        Picasso.get().load(imageUrl).into(myHolder.profileIv);
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

    //Set seen/delivered status of message
    if (i == chatList.size() - 1) {
        if (chatList.get(i).isSeen()) {
            myHolder.isSeenTv.setText("Seen");
        }
        else {
            myHolder.isSeenTv.setText("Delivered");

        }

    }
    else {
        myHolder.isSeenTv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

I commented out the 2 lines of code that were causing it to crash and I tried the new method under it. Can someone guide me in the right direction. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Used date format is incorrect. Use mm for minute and MM for month.

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: @VasilLukach thanks I edited the original post

Comment: @OleV.V. thanks I will look into that API anything to make this less painful. It shouldn't be so complicated to establish a proper timestamp lol

Comment: What does `chatList.get(i).getTimestamp()` return? If you can just give an example. Or even better, if you can modify it not to return a `String` but an `Instant` (from java.time; an `org.threeten.bp.Instant` if using the backport I mentioned).

Comment: @OleV.V. I think it was returning null

Comment: So when `chatList.get(i).getTimestamp()` returns `null`, which timestamp do you want to display? Current time??

Comment: Well the way I envision it is, there should only be a null return if there was no chat ever established. So at that point, if it's null I wouldn't want it to return anything. But if the user is is opening a previous chat, the time stamp should show when those messages were previously sent. Not the current time stamp. And that's the issue I'm having now. When I go into an existing chat, each message shows a time stamp of the current time, not when it was actually sent. @OleV.V. Sorry I'm so late with my reply btw

Comment: Thank you for explaining. I have modified my answer a bit after the new information.

Answer (score 1):

### java.time and ThreeTenABP

There are more than one unclear point about your question, but I am trying a suggestion. For my way of doing it I need two formatters:

```
private static DateTimeFormatter timestampFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .appendValue(ChronoField.INSTANT_SECONDS)
        .appendValue(ChronoField.MILLI_OF_SECOND, 3)
        .toFormatter();

private static DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a");
```

I understand that `chatList.get(i).getTimestamp()` may return `null`, but also that in this case you haven’t got any chat message to display. We need to take this possibility into account. The code below will give you the string `NA`. Modify if you want something else. Next it would seem from your commented-out code (the code that crashed on the `null`) that it may also return a `String` containing a long count of milliseconds since the epoch. So I am handling that situation too.

```
    int i = 0;
    String timeStamp = chatList.get(i).getTimestamp();

    String dateTime;
    if (timeStamp == null) {
        dateTime = "NA";
    } else {
        Instant inst = timestampFormatter.parse(timeStamp, Instant.FROM);
        dateTime = inst.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).format(dtf);
    }

    System.out.println(dateTime);
```

Example output in my time zone (Europe/Copenhagen) when `chatList.get(i).getTimestamp()` returned `1567890123456`:

> 09/07/2019 11:02 PM

### What went wrong in your code?

First case, when `timeStamp` is `null` and you try `Long.parseLong(timeStamp)`, you will get a `java.lang.NumberFormatException: null`. If your code doesn’t catch this exception, it crashes.

Second case, you were calling the `toString` method of your `SimpleDateFormat`. `SimpleDateFormat` doesn’t define a `toString` method itself so `Object.toStrng()` is called. This returns such a string as `java.text.SimpleDateFormat@4f47c0fb`. The class name and a funny hex value separated by an `@` sign.

However, you should probably not want to use `SimpleDateFormat` at all. That class is a notorious troublemaker and long outdated. Instead in my code I am using `DateTimeFormatter` and other classes from java.time, the modern Java date and time API.

### Question: Doesn’t java.time require Android API level 26?

java.time works nicely on both older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least **Java 6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in. In this case you need to substitute the constant `Instant.FROM` in the above code with the method reference `Instant::from`.
- In non-Android Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the modern classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On (older) Android use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. And make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use **toLocalizedPattern()** in place of toString() in

```
String dateTime = new SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm a", Locale.getDefault()).toString();
```

i.e you have to use it like this

```
String dateTime = new SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm a", Locale.getDefault()).toLocalizedPattern();
```

Comment: Expected output: `12/22/2019 05:00 PM`. Output from your code: `mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm a`. Not correct.