# Java: Formatting a Date inside of a string

Tags: java, date, casting, simpledateformat

I know I'm probably doing something wrong, but I am trying to format a `Date` that is currently stored inside of a string but it won't let me parse it to a `String` because it doesn't recognize it as a `Date` (because it's in a `String` variable) and won't let me format it because it cannot format it in its current state. For reference, I am making a time clock application.

I apologize if I'm doing something stupid but I am fairly new to this and have never used `SimpleDateFormat` before. I put some snippets of code below:

```java
ArrayList<String> punchHistoryTimes = new ArrayList<String>();
SimpleDateFormat sdf =new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");

public void updatePunchHistory(Sheet sheet){
    for(int rowNum:rowNumbers){
        punchHistoryTimes.add(sheet.getRow(rowNum).getCell(1).getStringCellValue());
        punchHistory.add(new JLabel(sheet.getRow(rowNum).getCell(0).getRichStringCellValue().getString()+ " " + sheet.getRow(rowNum).getCell(1).getRichStringCellValue().getString()+ " " + sheet.getRow(rowNum).getCell(2).getRichStringCellValue().getString()));
    }
}

//other code is above this but not relevant to the issue
currentEmployee.setEndTime(sdf.format(currentDate));
if(punchHistory.get(punchHistory.size()-1).getText().contains("Clocked In")){
    calcTimeWorked(punchHistory.get(punchHistoryTimes.size()-1).getText(),currentEmployee.getEndTime());
}else{
    //This line below is where the error is happening
    //value of currentEmployee.getStartTime() at error: 1654653731536
    //value of currentEmployee.getEndTime() at error: 07-06-2022 21:02:12
    //Both currentEmployee.getStartTime() and currentEmployee.getEndTime() are stored as Strings
    calcTimeWorked(currentEmployee.getStartTime(),currentEmployee.getEndTime());
}
currentEmployee.setHoursWorked(differenceInTime);
```

I tried using the debugger and it shows the error is that it cannot parse 1654653731536. I understand the issue but cannot get a solution. I believe the issue is because when it stores the value in the excel file it is storing the date as a string but then when it pulls the date back out of the excel later (the application would have been closed between these events) it views it as a string and does not recognize that there is a `Date` inside of the `String`. Is there any way to cast the `String` 1654653731536 to a `Date`?

Comment: Refer to [Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html) trail in Oracle's Java tutorials.

Comment: [Edit] your question and post the stack trace.

Comment: `sdf.format(currentDate)` - I am guessing that `currentDate` is not a `Date`

Comment: I strongly recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `ZonedDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter` and/or other classes from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: 1654653731536 are milliseconds since the epoch (beyond any reasonable doubt) representing 2022-06-08T02:02:11.536Z (UTC). `Instant.ofEpochMilli(1654653731536L)` should get you on the right track. To convert to your time zone use something like `Instant.ofEpochMilli(1654653731536L).atZone(ZoneId.of("Pacific/Guadalcanal"))`. With the mentioned example time zone I got `2022-06-08T13:02:11.536+11:00[Pacific/Guadalcanal]`, but you will substitute your own time zone or perhaps `ZoneId.systemDefault()`.

Comment: For parsing the milliseconds as a string see for example [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59468723/5772882). Assuming that you are not using the ThreeTen Backport, notice the point (bullet) about using `Instant::from` instead of `Instant.FROM`.

Comment: And obviously, if there is any way you can modify your employee class, store start and end time as `Instant` instead of `String`.

Comment: For dealing with the different strings that you have currently got I put together [this little demo](https://rextester.com/PKBBG48335). In addition to parsing the strings I am also calculating the work time. The current output is a `Duration` printed as `PT1H0.464S`, which means 1 hour 0.464 seconds. The `Duration` is fine for further processing or formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Your are tring to covert epoch date time , may below example will help you

```
import java.util.Date;

public class EpochToDateFormat {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Epoch time in milliseconds
        long epochTime = 1654653731536L;

        // Convert epoch time to Date
        Date date = new Date(epochTime);

        // Format Date to desired format
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(date);

        // Output formatted date
        System.out.println("Formatted Date: " + formattedDate);
    }
}
```

Comment: To be honest helping people how to use the notoriously troublesome `SImpleDateFormat` class is doing them an ill favour. They should forget about that class and instead use [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html).